# update totalpending and totalaccepted in table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Please help to update TotalPending and TotalAccepted in table tblInvitation using tblInvitationEmpStatus

1.tblInvitation

```
ID  Invitation           TotalPending   TotalAccepted
1   Group Meeting          0                0
2   Project discussion     0                0
3   Skype Call             0                0
```

2. tblInvitationEmpStatus

```
ID  EmpID        StatusType(1=Pending,2=Accepted)
1   101                1
1   102                1
1   103                2
2   101                2
2   102                2
3   104                1
3   105                2
3   106                2
```

Output tblInvitation

```
ID  Invitation           TotalPending   TotalAccepted
1   Group Meeting          2                1
2   Project discussion     0                2
3   Skype Call             1                2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregate` to find the count of `Pending` and `Accepted` status.

```
SELECT a.ID,
       a.Invitation,
       TotalPending = Count(CASE WHEN StatusType = 1 THEN 1 END),
       TotalAccepted = Count(CASE WHEN StatusType = 2 THEN 1 END) 
FROM   tblInvitation a
       JOIN tblInvitationEmpStatus b
         ON a.ID = b.ID
GROUP  BY a.ID,
          a.Invitation
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ccb7/1)**

To `Update` the `tblInvitation` table

```
Update A set
       TotalPending = Count(CASE WHEN StatusType = 1 THEN 1 END),
       TotalAccepted = Count(CASE WHEN StatusType = 2 THEN 1 END) 
FROM   tblInvitation a
       JOIN tblInvitationEmpStatus b
         ON a.ID = b.ID
GROUP  BY a.ID,
          a.Invitation
```

Comment: Please share the Update statement for to update these calculated count in table tblInvitation